# Facebook like button: data-width attribute is ignored on mobile devices

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I used the following html code for displaying FB "Like" button on our site:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MyCompany?ref=hl" data-send="false" data-width="400" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

On desktops everything looks fine. But I found out that on mobile devices data-width attribute is ignored and this is how the div with class fb-like looks after page is loaded:

```
<div class="fb-like fb_iframe_widget fb_iframe_widget_fluid" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MyCompany?ref=hl" data-send="false" data-width="400" data-show-faces="false" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="app_id=&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FMyCompany%3Fref%3Dhl&amp;locale=en_US&amp;sdk=joey&amp;send=false&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=400" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto;>
```

You can see that style attribute with "Width:100%" is added to the div. While on the desktops no inline style is added to this div.

In the console I receive the following error:

```
Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated.
```

with link to the file like.php which belongs to Facebook.

I don't know if this error message is connected with data-width problem on the mobile devices. Maybe someone already faced with this problem. I'll appreciate any help or explanation.

Answer (score 2):

There is how I solved this problem. I put div with class "fb-like" in container and set width of this parent container:

```
<div class="fb-wrapper">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MyPage?ref=hl" data-send="false" data-width="400" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fb-wrapper{float: right; width: 400px; height: 30px; overflow:hidden;}
```

I know, that it's not very beautiful solution. I'll appreciate any advices how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but I just "solved" this issue myself. Wrap the FB div in another div with display set to inline-block.